# How to view subfolder folder contents inside Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015

If I drag a folder of content to a project in Visual Studio 2015, the content is added, however, for each subfolder of content, instead of the folder being a tree, it's an icon, not allowing me to view what's inside the folder.

How can I make this folder a tree, so I can open it in Visual Studio and see the inside contents?

[image: It's a folder with not dropdown-ability!]

Comment: can you make a screenshot?

Comment: from where do you drag the folder? Windows Explorer?

Comment: You cannot see the files, mark the project and click on the refresh arrow button above.

Comment: @Legends tried selecting the project and clicking on the refresh icon to no avail! interestingly, if i click "Show all files" then they fold out, but then I see a load of other unnecessary files!

Answer (score 1):

Mark the project and click on

> "Show All Files"

like in the picture below

[image]

After that open the folder **mark only the needed files**, right-click and choose include.

After that click again on

> "Show All Files"

, to hide the once that are not included.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately doing this, I see all the obj files, project settings files and a load of other files that I'd rather not have cluttering up the solution view

Comment: I've updated the answer regarding your second question. So this is the solution to your question, mark it as an answer. Thanks.